# CancelAfter not executing after timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, task, cancellationtokensource

I have the following which is called in a Web Api controller.  Each task fires off a 3rd party API request.  Currently the first task that is completed is returned correctly, but the subsequent tasks that take longer than 500ms are running until completion.

```
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();            
        cts.CancelAfter(500);

        foreach (Models.Channel.IChannel channel in channels)
        {
            try
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    if (cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    channel.Data = channel.RequestOffers(new Models.Request.AvailabilityRequest()).Result;
                    availabilityResponse.Agents.Add(channel.Name);
                }, cts.Token));

                Task.WaitAny(tasks.ToArray());    
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                log.Error(ex);
            }
        }
```

Why aren't tasks taking longer than 500ms being cancelled?

Comment: Because there is no magic that will cancel your request `channel.RequestOffers`

Comment: How would I conjure up some magic to cancel the request channel.RequestOffers.  Does this need to be done within the method... and what is the purpose of CancelAfter ?